# How do I add a row in PhpSpreadsheet?

Tags: phpspreadsheet

I am using https://phpspreadsheet.readthedocs.io/ and I'd like to append a row to an existing XLSX file. Since the reader and write classes are different it seems I would need to read the entire sheet , do a couple `setCellValue` calls and then write the entire shebang back. Is this really the only? Isn't there a way to just ...  you know, append a row?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look to [the part the Documentation](https://phpspreadsheet.readthedocs.io/en/latest/topics/recipes/#inserting-rowscolumns).

I would use `$sheet->insertNewRowBefore($rowNumber, $count);`